# Как проскролить до нужного элемента в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, modal

по нажатию на якорь открываю мод окно и делаю скролл до нужного элемента. Но скролится не содержимое окна, а всё, что за ним. Вот код:

```
    $('.sas_link').click(function () {
      // если таблица не в мод окне
      if ($('.tarrif_details_container').is(':visible')) {
        // = плавный скролл
        scrollSmoothly.apply($('.sas_link'));
      } else {
        $('#moreAboutTarifs')
          .find('.btn')
          .click();
        setTimeout(
          function () {
            console.log('scroll');
            var destination = $('#sas').offset().top - 300;
            $('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)').animate(
              {
                scrollTop: destination
              },
              800
            );
            blinkElement($('#sas'));
          },
          500
        );
      }
    });
```

Нужно помочь с кодом, который после "else", пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Ты анимируешь селектор $('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)'), конечно будет скролиться вся страница. Если хочешь анимировать скролл внутри блока, то перепиши селектор и все будет норм.

Comment: переписал, не работает(